Duplicate class okhttp3.Interceptor found in module: appdynamics-injector build failure
I am trying to install AppDynamics to an Android Gradle project, but running into a build-time error below...
Duplicate class okhttp3.Interceptor found in modules jetified-appdynamics-injector-24.4.0 (com.appdynamics:appdynamics-injector:24.4.0) and jetified-okhttp-4.12.0 (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0) 
Duplicate class okhttp3.Interceptor$Chain found in modules jetified-appdynamics-injector-24.4.0 (com.appdynamics:appdynamics-injector:24.4.0) and jetified-okhttp-4.12.0 (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0) 
Gradle:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
AppDynamics:
 // Appdynamics     val appDynamicsVersion = "24.4.0"     implementation("com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:$appDynamicsVersion")     implementation("com.appdynamics:appdynamics-runtime:$appDynamicsVersion")
// OKHTTP     val okHttpVersion = "4.12.0"     implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion")     implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion")
I just need the project to compile and build... any help appreciate it advance! Tried restarting and invalidating studio cache, etc... does not work. I noticed that the implementation("com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:$appDynamicsVersion") is the specific dependency that pulls in this particular issue.

try removing the implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion")     implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion").

I actually tried that already... the interceptor that it's complaining about comes from the okhttp3 library: implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion") and NOT the logging library you specified above, so that won't work
